# What does it mean when I say "She is always early for work on a Monday"?

Tags: indefinite-article

What does it indicate when we use an indefinite article before Monday or any other day?

Comment: The optional article means ***nothing at all*** in your context. My guess is most native speakers *wouldn't* include it *(**She is always early for work on Monday**)*, but it's just a meaningless stylistic choice. Note that it's also quite natural to pluralise ***Mondays*** here, and I'd be pretty certain doing *that* would be more common than actually including the indefinite article. But that wouldn't affect the meaning either.

Comment: I know that I can pluralize Mondays, but the point is that I found this context in a Cambridge English book and the question was to organize some mixed-up words into correct sentences and this is the first time I come up against such usage.

Comment: Are you saying that a true *Anglophone* teaching resource set you the task of rearranging a mixed-up set of words ***including that indefinite article**?* That strikes me as a little odd, given how [relatively uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+work+on+Monday%2Cfor+work+on+a+Monday%2Cfor+work+on+Mondays&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20work%20on%20Monday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20work%20on%20a%20Monday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20work%20on%20Mondays%3B%2Cc0) it is to include the article. But it ***is*** "valid", though.

Answer (score 2):

**a** is an [indefinite article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/the-indefinite-article-a-and-an): it means that you are not talking about a specific **whatever** that you have already referred to. For example, if you said "I would like **an** apple", it means that you are not talking about any particular apple- **any** apple would do.

In this case, non-specific means that she is early for work on **any** Monday.